# Calculate PHP Values

Tags: php

So if someone fills my form i will get the results of what they filled, but if they choose some numbers in the select form like 2 persons, 2 kids, 1 baby, then i want to send the total output (5) in the php message, Right now is sending only the values:

```
$message = 
'Persons: ' . $_POST['pers']. "\n" .
'Kids: ' . $_POST['kids']. "\n" .
'Babys: ' . $_POST['babys']. "\n" .
```

So how send the total output of the selected values? 
And show it like something like this:

```
'Total person: ' . $_POST['totalpersons']. "\n" .
```

So i mean: If a user select 2 persons, 2 kids and 1 baby's in a form , Then i want to post the TOTAL Amount of Persons, so that is : ( 3+2+1 = **5** )  I want only echo the total persons so that is : **5**

This is the solution for me :

```
$totalpersons = $_POST['pers'] + $_POST['kids'] + $_POST['babys'];

'Total persons: ' . $totalpersons . '\n' .
```

Comment: In your example, is `$_POST['kids']` set to the number `2`, or set to a string `2 kids`?

Comment: Do some arithmetic.  total persons = persons + kids + babies

Comment: is there any reason why a simple addition won't work?

Comment: Show the values that you are getting right now in the $_POST variables.  Is it just numbers? or its numbers and alphabets?

Comment: They are just numbers

Answer (score 3):

funky method

```
echo array_sum($_POST['pers'],$_POST['kids'],$_POST['babys']);
```

Comment: What is the benefit over just adding the values? Does not make the code shorter and might add unwanted side effects if someone doesn't know exactly what the method does?

Comment: its php, if you cant do it 10 ways, your not imagnitive enough.

Comment: Well, besides the fact that redeclaring the variables does not have anything to do with using `array_sum()` or not, I really just asked out of honest and sincere curiosity, not because I wanted to be an asshole.

Comment: @Dagon Friend of yours? http://stackoverflow.com/q/30441493/

Comment: @Fred-ii- nah, all my friends know how to multiply 2 numbers together :-)

Answer (score 1):

Intval should be helpful

```
$totalpersons = intval($_POST['pers']) + intval($_POST['kids']) + intval($_POST['babys']);
```

Comment: Personally I wouldn't do this. If for some reason the POST variables don't contain an Int, but a string instead that can't be converted to the expected int, you might get some really weird results by converting them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy:

```
$totalpersons = $_POST['pers'] + $_POST['kids'] + $_POST['babys'];

'Total persons: ' . $totalpersons . '\n' .
```

This is assuming those 3 POST variables in your example contain the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to check whether the values you got are actually numbers. `is_numeric()` comes handy for that. After that you can simply add up the numbers:

```
$persons = $_POST['pers'];
$kids = $_POST['kids'];
$babys = $_POST['babys'];

if(is_numeric($persons) && is_numeric($kids) && is_numeric($babys)) {
    $output = $persons + $kids + $babys;
} else {
    // find a different solution
}
```

You may also want to think about what happens if someone gives you one and a half baby... and what you're gonna do with it.

Comment: Why re-declare instead of using `$_POST` values directly?

Comment: It makes it more readable. And the code also gets more maintainable. E.g. if you want to so some conversions on the values later, this way you can easily do it without having to change the values in `$_POST` or change multiple spots of your code. But mainly it's way less annoying to type. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Get the values, get the interger value using `intval` function and add them. Also use an `isset` to see if all variables are set, else call an error.

```
if(isset($_POST["pers"] && isset($_POST["kids"] && isset($_POST["babys"]){
$total = intval($_POST["pers"]) + intval($_POST["kids"]) + intval($_POST[
"babys"]);
echo $total;
}
else{
//echo an error.
echo "inputs missing";
}
```

using isset is recommended, else if one of them is not set, you would be giving wrong answers